# routerlink: ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I use Angular 6 in my CRUD application, and I have this structure of components:

```
root: app.component
   - topic.component
     - create-topic.componentI
   - answer.component
```

I have a button in `topic.component` that has a `routerlink` to `create-topic component`:

```html
<a routerLink="add-topic">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">New Topic</button>
</a>
```

and in the template of `topic.component` I have this where I want to show the template of `create-topic`:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is the configuration of `app.routing.module`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'add-topic', component: CreateTopicComponent }
]
```

All other routes I have are working except this one, everytime I click on the button I get this:

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
>   resolvePromisehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5787:31
>   resolvePromisehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5744:17
>   scheduleResolveOrRejecthttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5846:17
>   invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5394:17
>   onInvokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:58217:24
>   invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5393:17
>   runTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5161:28
>   drainMicroTaskQueuehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5568:25
>   invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5473:21
>   invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6513:9
>   globalZoneAwareCallbackhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6539:17

I don't know where to look and what this error means ? What am I missing?
I can't find any other stackoverflow question that is similar to my issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be [routerLink]="['add-top']" ?

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: I'm using firefox. and @rrd I usually use routerlink that way and It works fine  without brakets

Comment: @Souad then you have to start link with a slash `routerLink="/add-topic"`.

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko that worked. please add an answer thank you so much. I was missing a slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: check the screenshot]
Router link is given in this way `[routerLink]="['/your-path']"`

Comment: @Exterminator, yeah my bad, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Add [routerLink]="['add-topic']" . This should work

Comment: add-topic should be a string, I assume in this way it should look like `[routerLink]="['', 'add-topic']"`

Comment: Correct . Modified my answer